# How to implement a function in a class which may or may not be over-ridden in sub class?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

Currently there is a class say A, which has final method say mainMethod() and it calls three methods a(), b() and c(). Now, the child class has to implement a and b so I made them abstract. But c may not be needed. How do I achieve it? I am using PHP.

Comment: Please take the time to come up with an actual code example. As the question is  currently written, it's hard to see exactly the problem you are having, and the solution proposed here may not solve your problem the you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Just create an empty non-abstract method and in the comments describe that it may be overwritten. E.g:

```
abstract class A 
{
    public abstract function a();
    public abstract function b();

    /**
     * This method may be overwritten for purpose X ...
     */
    public function c() 
    {
        /* empty */
    }
}
```

This way you can call `c()`, and it may or may not have any function. The inheriting class is forced to implement `a()` and `b()`, and can optionally overwrite `c()`. A good php editor like NetBeans or whatever is capable of code hinting, where also the comment will be shown, so the programmer is informed about the purpose of the function.

Comment: I thought of this too, but leaving empty methods is a bad practice. Is there any other way?

Comment: I neither think that it is bad practice, nor do I think that there is another way. You can't call an undefined method, and neither can you create an abstract method that need not be implemented.

Comment: An interface would probably be the better tool to enforce an implementation for `a()` and `b()`